# Uploading PNG files to SharePoint not possible

Tags: 2010, file-upload, document-upload

I can upload BNP files, not JPG or PNG. I set PNG as a file type for search.

I set security low for the local intranet and trusted sites settings in Internet Explorer.

I used the paint program to change the PNG file to a BNP file and that worked, but I need to keep it as a PNG file. File size has been as small as 24 kb. The PNG file comes up fine in Windows Photo Viewer.

Comment: thanks Gennady G. I am the farm administrator and the png and jpg files are not blocked anywhere.

Comment: Do you get some sort of error message when you try and upload jpg or png files?

Comment: after trying to upload for about an hour it just says:This page can’t be displayed

Comment: Also png files that were saved before cannot be read.

Answer (score 0):

Hm..

Check if uploading *.jpg and *.png files is not restricted in CA:
[Manage blocked file types in SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262496.aspx)

- Verify that you have the following administrative credentials. You must be a farm administrator on the server.
- In Central Administration, click Security.
     On the Security page, in the General Security section, click Define blocked file types.
- On the Blocked File Types page, if you want to change the selected web application, on the Web Application menu, click Change
  Web Application. Use the Select Web Application page to select a web
  application.
- Do one of the following:
     To block an additional file type, scroll to the bottom of the Type each file name extension on a separate line text box, type the
  file name extension that you want to block, and then click OK.

Strange if somebody put them there but..

Answer (score 0):

PNG files might not be blocked, but due to other issues such as file name, URL size it might not be copying and seems a file type blocking issue

Answer (score 0):

In central admin, security -> Blocked file types and that should give the list of extensions blocked